# AS3 create a textField from a class

Tags: actionscript-3

I created a document class for an empty stage and would like to create an output class which is imported into the document class.

Inside the output class I would like to create a textField with the methods to set and read the text.

a) empty stage with document class "tommy"

b) document class "tommy"

```
package  {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import cOutput;

  public class tommy extends MovieClip {
    var _loc_1:cOutput;

    public function tommy() {
      _loc_6 = new cOutput;
      _loc_6.setOutput();//("hurra");       
    }
  }
}
```

c) output class cOutput (with or without extends Movieclip)

```
package {
  //import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import fl.controls.TextInput;

  public class cOutput{ //extends MovieClip {
    public var texteField:TextInput;

    public function cOutput() {
      texteField = new TextInput();
      addChild(texteField);
      texteField.text = "Seriously... I need to be displayed."
    }
    public function setOutput(printValue:String){
      texteField.text = printValue;
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving "Definition fl.controls:TextInput could not be found".

I read that you need to have this in the library (I dragged a text field as classic text, input text on stage).
Seems I am not getting this working.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TextField` class instead of the `TextInput` class. The `TextField` class is the most basic text component:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html

On a side note, your `addChild()` call won't do anything, as `cOutput` isn't a display object.

Comment: Thanks. I made it TextInput and it did not work. Then (ontop of TextInput) I added cOutput as Sprite (or MovieClip) and still nothing happened. Then I added a addChild(_loc_6) to the tommy class and it shows up. Can you explain, why I have to add _loc_6 to the stage though I am adding a sprite inside cOutput?

Comment: when you added `cOutput` to `_loc_6`, you're just adding it as a child - which is perfectly fine. The problem is that `_loc_6` wasn't added to the `stage` (or the `tommy` class), so you didn't see it. It's only when you added the `_loc_6` class to the `tommy` class, that it's shown (flash letting you do this means that you can build up a display hierarchy and only show it when it's finished). You can add the `cOutput` class directly to the `tommy` class to show it straight away if you want.